# Read jpg, edit pixel and save without loss

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

i am writing program which can load `JPG` file, and edit pixel `0,0` color to `red` and save JPG without loss. It's possible?

My program get exception on line `PropertyItem propItem = image1.GetPropertyItem(20624);`, i don't know why.

Error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Code

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile("1789594.jpg");

Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(image1);
bitmap1.GetPixel(0, 0);
Color pixelColor = bitmap1.GetPixel(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(pixelColor.R + " - " + pixelColor.G + " - " + pixelColor.B);
Console.ReadLine();
Color redColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
bitmap1.SetPixel(0, 0, redColor);
image1 = (Image)bitmap1;
// Get a PropertyItem from image1. Because PropertyItem does not
// have public constructor, you first need to get existing PropertyItem
PropertyItem propItem = image1.GetPropertyItem(20624);

// Change the ID of the PropertyItem.
propItem.Id = 20625;

// Set the new PropertyItem for image1.
image1.SetPropertyItem(propItem);

// Save the image.
image1.Save("outputcsharp.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //jpg
```

Comment: "save jpg" and "without loss" are pretty much mutually exclusive as jpg is a lossy compression and you will always generate artifacts. Try using PNG or TIFF. Nothing to do with your exception however.

Comment: *save JPG without loss* Clearly if you use standard classes for JPG you can't obtain this result. You'll probably have to modify the JPG "manually": load the [macroblock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroblock), modify it and resave it. In this way only that macroblock will have the quality reduced.

Comment: You can control the quality of the jpeg you save. What are all those lines doing in yopur code when you really need just 3 lines??? (`Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap ) Image.FromFile("1789594.jpg"); image1 .SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0); image1.Save(..)`

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you are doing the colour change in such a complex way, instead of the way that TaW suggested?

Comment: steganography  and jpg do not go together well. If you insist you will either: have to resort to xanatos' adivce of working with the raw  jpeg data, with the help of a library or maybe you can succeed be adding a check to see if the important pixels have indeed survived the saving. Less obtrusive with jpg but a lot harder than using png!

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.getpropertyitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the exception: _The image format of this image does not support property items._

Comment: Can you recommend me some library for JPEG without loss ?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer this from the JPEG perspective, not C#. There is no way to edit pixels in JPEG and save with no loss.

The JPEG process has several steps that introduce loss.

You can minimize the changes by
1) Using the same sampling; and
2) Same quantization tables
as in the original source file.

One of the changes in JPEG is that it converts to the YCbCr color space before compression. There is not a 1-to-1 mapping between RGB and YCbCr. So you can set RGB pixel values, compress, expand and find they are significantly different just from that transformation.

I know nothing about C# but, in the documentation PropertyID 20624 is the luminance quantization table.
It looks like your code is trying to make that the chrominance quantization table.

That's likely to have bizarre effects even if you achieve your result.

I come back and add this C# guess---

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(image1);
```

C# might think image1 is a JPEG and that bitmap1 is NOT a JPEG. Thus, trying to retrieve JPEG specific attributes from a non-JPEG image causes the argument error.